# How to correctly align caption with code listing

Tags: listings, captions

I am using the listing package to display my source code as follows:

```
\lstset{language=C++,basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,emptylines=1,breaklines=true,backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray},xleftmargin=-1.cm,frame=lr,framesep=8pt,framerule=0pt}
\lstset{numbers=left,tabsize=2}
```

By using `xleftmargin=-1.cm`, I am able to slightly push the code listing to the left into the margin. 
The resulting layout is shown below:

[image]

As you can see the caption is not correctly aligned with the code listing. I would like to push the listing's caption to the left in a similar way so that both code listing and captions are aligned and cover the same page length.

**Edit** As requested,  here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}      
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color} \usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,sl,textfont=normal,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}    
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{javared}{rgb}{0.6,0,0} % for strings
\definecolor{javagreen}{rgb}{0.25,0.5,0.35} % comments
\definecolor{javapurple}{rgb}{0.5,0,0.35} % keywords
\definecolor{javadocblue}{rgb}{0.25,0.35,0.75} % javadoc

\lstset{
keywordstyle=\color{javapurple}\bfseries,
stringstyle=\color{javared},
commentstyle=\color{javagreen},
morecomment=[s][\color{javadocblue}]{/**}{*/}}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\lstset{language=C++,basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,emptylines=1,breaklines=true,backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray},xleftmargin=-1.cm,frame=lr,framesep=8pt,framerule=0pt}
\lstset{numbers=left,tabsize=2}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=random02.cpp]
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>
int main(){
time_t seed = time(nullptr);
std::mt19937 randomEngine(seed);
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1,6);
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){
std::cout << dist(randomEngine) << std::endl;
}
}
\end{lstlisting}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

**Edit 2**: Only code listings should be impacted by this formatting. Other captions should be displayed with their default style defined in the document

Comment: Please post a compilable code starting with `\begin{document}` and ending with `\end{document}`, not just code snippets.

Comment: Can you please make your code compilable? Including a documentclass and the necessary packages?

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited the MWE to be compilable and made sure to test before submitting.